# Jar run in Windows but not in Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, jar

I made a runnable jar with external libraries. Under Windows I use a bat file to run the application (`java -Djava.library.path=./dist/lib -cp ./dist/Navegador.jar; navegador.Main`) and it works properly.

I created a sh file to run the application under Linux, but Im getting the following error while trying to execute it in terminal:

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
chrriis/dj/nativeswing/NativeSwing`

My Manifest.mf is like this:

`Class-Path: lib/DJNativeSwing-SWT.jar lib/DJNativeSwing-SWTAPI.jar lib
 /DJNativeSwing-SWTCore.jar lib/MozillaInterfaces-1.8.1.3.jar lib/DJNa
 tiveSwing.jar lib/swt.jar`

Why this jar doesn't work under Linux?

Comment: How do you run it on linux? Cat your .sh file here.

Comment: sh file is like bat one: `#!bin/bash java -Djava.library.path=./dist/lib -cp ./dist/Navegador.jar; navegador.Main`

Comment: Remove the `;` after `./dist/Navegador.jar`

Comment: I got the same error after removing semicolon. Maybe I need a special sintaxis for running jar in Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you one or two `lib` directories?  You have

```
-Djava.library.path=./dist/lib
```

but you also have

```
 lib/DJNativeSwing.jar
```

Does this mean you have a `dist/lib` and `lib` directory or should they be the same?

Comment: I have one lib directory. Main folder contains `dist` and `sh`. Inside `dist` I have `lib` folder and `Runnable jar`. Inside `lib` folder I have all my jar dependencies.

Comment: In that case, it is only correct to use one of `dist/lib` or `lib`.

Comment: I changed sh file for this `#!bin/bash java -jar ./dist/Navegador.jar navegador.Main` and terminal returns same error

Comment: From the same directory type `ls -l lib/DJNativeSwing.jar`

Comment: This is what console returned: `-rwxrwxrwx. 1 admin admin 75266 mar 24  2009 dist/lib/DJNativeSwing.jar`

Comment: So if the file is in `dist/lib`, that is what it should say in the manifest as well.

Comment: A simpler solution is to change your start up script. to `#!bin/bash cd ./dist ; java -Djava.library.path=lib -cp Navegador.jar navegador.Main`

Comment: Ok, i will check it tomorrow (not in the office now) and update with the result. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I tried your solution and didn't work but I saw something interesting. If I remove all information from `Class-path` in `MANIFEST.MF` it still returns same NoClassFound error and if I run the jar file using only `java -jar Navegador.jar` it returns same error again. So it is ignoring all information to libraries path. Any idea of why is this happening?

Comment: It is not find the libraries where you have them in the class path. Try adding them to the command line with `-cp lib/*`

Comment: Still doesn't work. If I found the solution I will post it here. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Solved. Searching the web I found a post from someone who had had a similar problem. The solution has been to add a dependency (JNA) which was needed to run the application in Linux. Although the error message said that `chrriis / dj / nativeswing / NativeSwing` was not found the real dependency missing was JNA.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run the application under Linux because you are missing a native lib (it's called `.so` under linux, `.dll` under Windows).

Comment: I'm using NativeSwing jar dependencies for Linux (not the files I used for Windows application), so your answer is absolutely wrong.